# Python: Object Has No Attribute Error : An array

Tags: python, arrays, class

```
class foo:
    #initially
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes1=[]
        self.nodes2=[]
        self.edges=[]

    def add_node(self,type,x,y):
        if type==1:
            self.nodes1.append(node1(x,y))


class node1:
    def __init__(self,x,y): #Getting coordinates from outside while creating the class.
        self.x=x
        self.y=y


b_foo = foo 
b_foo.add_node(b_foo,1,0,1)
```

I try to add an element to the class' array. 
This code gives an error like this:

> AttributeError: type object 'bipartite' has no attribute 'nodes1'

Comment: You are not creating the instance of class properly. Replace last second line with this b_foo = foo()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create an **instance** of your class:

```
b_foo = foo() # creates a class instance
b_foo.add_node(1,0,1) # "self" is passed implicitly
```